# How to stop page refresh in a Liveview template

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

My LiveView app sets some initial states (e.g, button_label) in the `mount`function. The template appears to be re-mounted as it goes through some message passing.

In the following example, the button label is initially set to "Click to run", and when the button is clicked, it successfully changes to "Running..." and then "Still in progrss". However, `mount` is automatically run again, and the label goes back to "Click to run". The desired behavior is that the label stays as "Still in progress" until another message is received indicating the process is completed later in the process.

What triggers the re-mounting, and how can I stop that?

```
def mount(_params, _session, socket) do
   {:ok, assign(socket, button_label: "Click to run")}

def handle_event("run_process", value, socket) do
    live_view = self()

    Task.start(fn ->
      result = "Some tasks to run here"  
      send(live_view, {:in_progress, result})
    end)

    {:noreply, assign(socket, button_label: "Running..")}

def handle_info({:in_progress, result}, socket) do
    IO.inspect("result", label: "in_progress ++")
    {:noreply, assign(socket, button_label: "Still in progress")}
end


[Leex]
<button phx-click="run_process"><%= @button_label %> </button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@schrockwell at the Elixir slack channel kindly provided this answer. It solved my problem.

Try adding the type="button" attribute to the  tag

That will prevent the form from trying to be submitted on the button click.

```
[Leex]
<button type="button" phx-click="run_process"><%= @button_label %> </button>
```